# Gem::LoadError installing ruby 1.9.2, in macbook snow leopard

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I have been trying to install and run rubyonrails in my macbook Snow Leoppard 10.6.8, with Ruby 1.9.2-p290.

When I write `bundle install` im having this problem, not just with Postgres also with SQLite and MySQL.

> Installing pg (0.11.0) `/Users/felipevelasquez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:585`:in `initialize': Permission denied -`/Users/felipevelasquez/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pg-0.11.0/Rakefile` (Errno::EACCES)

When I write `sudo bundle install` I have this:

> /Users/felipevelasquez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [mime-types-1.16, minitest-1.6.0, rack-1.3.2, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8, rest-client-1.6.7, sequel-3.20.0, sinatra-1.0, sqlite3-1.3.4, sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3, taps-0.3.23] (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: You shouldn't be using `sudo` for a bundle install.

Comment: I did it, but i have this:  sudo bundle install
/Users/felipevelasquez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [mime-types-1.16, minitest-1.6.0, rack-1.3.2, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8, rest-client-1.6.7, sequel-3.20.0, sinatra-1.0, sqlite3-1.3.4, sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3, taps-0.3.23] (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: Don't use sudo. It's probably the cause of this in the first place. rvm makes sudo unnecessary.

Comment: Then i have this: Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/felipevelasquez/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pg-0.11.0/Rakefile
An error occured while installing pg (0.11.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.11.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: You've used sudo for other things you shouldn't have. You should uninstall rvm and reinstall it, and all your gems as well without sudo.

Answer (score -1):

Cause of this problem is this: this could be a rvm bug, I have experienced too earlier.

the directory to write has no permission, while you escalating the privilege, the gem env and PATH info is not passed into it.

You can either try to install rvm and ruby. OR export your env and path with sudo command. for example:

```
sudo export GEM_HOME = /path/to/gem_home && bundle install
```

Comment: it's not a bug in RVM, just do not use sudo with RVM, it's not necessary, if you would read the rvm docs - you would knew it -> https://rvm.io

Comment: Ok thanks! i tried installing rvm, but when install ruby 1.9.2: Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/felipevelasquez/.rvm/usr"  ', please read /Users/felipevelasquez/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/yaml/configure.log There has been an error while running configure.Error running 'make ', please read /Users/felipevelasquez/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/yaml/make.log Database file /Users/felipevelasquez/.rvm/config/packages does not exist.

There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.